# First Lisp with macros?

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp, common-lisp

McCarthy's original Lisp and some number of incarnations thereafter did not have a macro facility like we now have in Common Lisp, Clojure, Scheme, etc...  This I know.

However, it is unclear to me exactly how macros came to be, what implementation(s) had them first, and what motivated them.  References to papers and source would be ideal if you please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [The Evolution of Lisp](http://www.dreamsongs.com/NewFiles/Hopl2.pdf) (PDF):

*Macros appear to have been introduced into Lisp by Timothy P. Hart in 1963 in a short MIT AI Memo [Hart, 1963]*

See:

> AIM-57 Author[s]: Timothy P. Hart
>
> MACRO Definitions for LISP
>
> October 1963
>
> https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6111
>
> In LISP 1.5 special forms are used for
> three logically separate purposes: a)
> to reach the alist, b) to allow
> functions to have an indefinite number
> of arguments, and c) to keep arguments
> from being evaluated. New LISP
> interpreters can easily satisfy need
> (a) by making the alist a SPECIAL-type
> or APVAL-type entity. Uses (b) and (c)
> can be replaced by incorporating a
> MACRO instruction expander in define.
> I am proposing such an expander.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I'mm looking forward to digging into it this weekend.

Answer (score 9):

John Shutt's [PhD thesis](http://www.wpi.edu/Pubs/ETD/Available/etd-090110-124904/unrestricted/jshutt.pdf) first part concerns the history of lisps, including the introduction of macros, I believe.  It's not entirely clear to me on reading, but it seems that he claims that macros are more-or-less identified with an "extensible languages" movement (which is independent of lisp), and that M.D. McIlroy's 1960 paper, "Macro Extension Instructions of Compiler Languages", was foundational to the extensible languages movement...  implying that macros were introduced to the academic literature in 1960.

Comment: Hmmm.  I wish there was a way to mark multiple answers as "the answer". :-(